# Do Linux directory permissions overrule file permissions?

Tags: linux, permissions

```
drwxrwxrwx  2 user1 user1 4096 Jun 21 11:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 16 user1 user1 4096 Jun 21 11:25 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 user1 user1   15 Jun 21 11:25 access.txt
```

The file access.txt is owned by user **user1** but the directory has open access to the world (777).

If I log in with **user2**, I can delete **access.txt** even though **user2** does not have write permissions to it. So does directory permissions take precedence over file permissions? Perhaps that not the best way to describe it, but just looking for a basic explanation here.

Comment: You can remove `access.txt` because you have *write* permission to the directory. You could remove that file even if it belonged to `root`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlinking `access.txt` from the directory is not a change to `access.txt`, but a change to the directory, so user2's write permission on the *directory* is what is relevant.

The write permission on the *file* would be of interest if user2 wanted to modify the file, rather than the containing directory.

Comment: very helpful. Thank you